# Could not start zookeeper for kafka on windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I have the following folder structure:

[image]

from `C:\Program Files\kafka\kafka_2.11-0.11.0.0` frolder I try to execute following command:

```
bin\windows\zookeeper-server-start.bat config\zookeeper.properties
```

and it reponds with following message:

```
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I tried to use several another variants but I still see errors:

```
C:\Program Files\kafka\kafka_2.11-0.11.0.0>bin\windows\zookeeper-server-start.bat
USAGE: bin\windows\zookeeper-server-start.bat zookeeper.properties
```

---

```
C:\Program Files\kafka\kafka_2.11-0.11.0.0>bin\windows\zookeeper-server-start.bat C:\Program Files\kafka\kafka_2.11-0.11.0.0\config\zookeeper.properties
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

---

```
C:\Program Files\kafka\kafka_2.11-0.11.0.0>bin\windows\zookeeper-server-start.bat 'C:\Program Files\kafka\kafka_2.11-0.11.0.0\config\zookeeper.properties'
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

What do I wrong?

Comment: FYI, There is an open JIRA on the Kafka project regarding this issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-4860. It should be fixed in one of the upcoming releases.

Answer (score 6):

You can resolve this issue by declaring path in environment variable for your kafka folder like this C:\kafka_2.12-2.8.0\bin\windows and after that open a fresh terminal and try to run the same command and it will work hopefully.

Comment: your answer helped me I was running this command from bin directory but when I used it from windows it worked. Thank You
Command : : zookeeper-server-start.bat ..\..\config\zookeeper.properties

Answer (score 1):

Paths containing spaces need to be enquoted (i.e. `"C:\Program Files\kafka\"` instead of `C:\Program Files\kafka\`).

The simplest solution would be to move your `kafka` folder to a path which contains no spaces, such as `C:\kafka`, and adjust the configuration file accordingly.

Another option would be to edit your configuration files (and possibly the batch files as well) and to enquote the paths which contain spaces.

A third, unrecommended option would be to use the 8.3 path syntax, which means editing the config and batch files to use `C:\Progra~1\kafka` instead of `C:\Program Files\kafka`

Comment: I already inside Program Files directory. What should I quote?

Comment: What should I do exactly ?

Comment: The paths inside zookeeper.properties. But I recommend you start by moving the folders to a spaceless path, which would get you an up and running system quickly, and only then tackle the issue of running it from Program Files.

Comment: dataDir=/tmp/zookeeper    
clientPort=2181   
maxClientCnxns=0

Comment: @ M.A. Hanin I don't see paths here

Comment: Edit dataDir=/tmp/zookeeper to C:\zookeeper-3.4.9\data(set it as per your requirement)

Comment: @M.A. Hanin Your suggestion of using quoted path is not working. It is giving this error:      [2017-09-02 01:19:53,059] FATAL  (kafka.Kafka$)
    java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <"> at index 0: "C:kafka_2.11-0.11.0.0kafka-logs"\meta.properties.tmp
            at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.normalize(WindowsPathParser.java:182)
            at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:153)
            at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:77)
            at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.parse(WindowsPath.java:94)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
bin\windows\zookeeper-server-start.bat .. \ ..\config\zookeeper.properties
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue when I want to run server. Actually this had happened due to the long path where you had saved your Kafka Folder. Previously I had saved my Kafka folder in User's Directory ("C:\Users\xxxx\xxxx\kafka_2.13-2.8.0"). So after changing path of my Kafka folder to ("C:") it got solved.

Answer (score 1):

The path is too long, move the folder to "C:\kafka_2.11-0.11.0.0" and then run the command again, this should work.

Answer (score 0):

Commands to follow for kafka and zookeeper set up:

1. Download kafka from https://dlcdn.apache.org/kafka/3.5.0/kafka_2.13-3.5.0.tgz
   And store into D:\Learning\kafka then unzip it there only.
2. Set path in environment veriable as D:\Learning\kafka\kafka_2.13-3.5.0\bin\windows
3. Start the kafka –
   Open cmd in D:\Learning\kafka\kafka_2.13-3.5.0\bin\windows> and run

   zookeeper-server-start.bat ....\config\zookeeper.properties

Open another cmd  in D:\Learning\kafka\kafka_2.13-3.5.0\bin\windows> and run

```
kafka-server-start.bat ..\..\config\server.properties
```

4. Create the topic to store your events -
   Open another cmd  in D:\Learning\kafka\kafka_2.13-3.5.0\bin\windows> and run

   kafka-topics.bat --create --topic quickstart-events --bootstrap-server localhost:9092
   kafka-topics.bat --describe --topic quickstart-events --bootstrap-server localhost:9092
5. Write some topics into the topic –
   Open another cmd  in D:\Learning\kafka\kafka_2.13-3.5.0\bin\windows> and run

   kafka-console-producer.bat --topic quickstart-events --bootstrap-server localhost:9092
   This is my first event
   This is my second event
6. Read the events –
   Open another cmd  in D:\Learning\kafka\kafka_2.13-3.5.0\bin\windows> and run

   kafka-console-consumer.bat --topic quickstart-events --from-beginning --bootstrap-server localhost:9092

Answer (score 0):

Edit the server.properties file

```
log dirs = /temp/kafka-logs
```

To

```
log dirs = C:/kafka/kafka_2.13/kafka-logs
```

(the above is the path file in my case)

Also, edit the `zookeeper.properties`

```
dataDir = C:/kafka/kafka_2.13/zookeeper-data
```

Basically, change the property files with your actual file location and it will clear all the issues.